# Can I use the unused 1G of 4G on a 32bit machine as a ramdisk?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 32-bit, ramdisk

I have a machine with 4G of RAM, but running 32bit windows 7, so can only see 3G. I have read somwhere recently that that unused 1G can be used as a RamDisk. Is this true? What sort of program allows that, and how does it address that gig of RAM?

Comment: G = Gravitational constant. GB = Gigabyte.

Comment: well, if you wanna get pedantic, it would be Gibibyte since we're talking about RAM. So GiB.

Comment: I don't want to be pedantic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No,

This is because the processor does not know how to access the space.

[More detail on "why?"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/dude-wheres-my-4-gigabytes-of-ram.html)

[if you REALLY want to give it a shot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929605)

Answer (score 2):

Superspeed Ramdisk -> Faq -> Unmanaged Memory

Answer (score 1):

I have been using VSuite RAMdisk (Free Edition) and it works.

I have not had any problems so far.

I have WinXP, 4GB of RAM, my RAMdisk is almost 1GB, and windows reports 3,144,680 KB physical memory available.

Answer (score -1):

I doesn't matter what you do or what program you use to "use" this "unused" 1G sooner or later a conflict will lead you to a BSOD or a crash. I've been trying at least 20 (Ramdisk, Russian things, Patchin PAE, etc..etc..) method/programs and believe me the result is just the same. This area is reserved by Windows to do some tasks (hardware reserved: card graphics.... Maybe not always by sooner or later it will use it! Don't waste your time looking for this miraculous method. Bill is a naughty boy, but this time is not his fault!